# Are Python Class Variables pointers?

Tags: python

I have been unable to find the answer to this on the Python documentation page (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). I need to know this because I am working with large objects, and this would affect whether it is feasible to have a large object as a class variable. For example:

```
class LargeList:
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        self.mylist = mylist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = range(0, 1000000000)
    largelist = LargeList(x)
```

Would this object store a pointer to x?

Comment: Yes, it would - the `list` object created by `range` would be accessible via `largelist.mylist`. They're generally referred to as *"references"* in Python, rather than *"pointers"*, although the effect is much the same.

Comment: Actually is is instance variable not class.

Comment: But do also note that in CPython, a "reference" is a pointer to a PyObject-like struct defined in the C source (or in your own extension module). The syntax `class Foo ...` is interpreted by executing the necessary C machinery to define a new PyObject-like type. Further, and probably more relevant here, in Python, a basic `list` is really a contiguous array *of pointers* and it is *not* a pointer to a contiguous array of memory locations. When a list is constructed, it *might* be contiguous in memory too, but there's no guarantee it won't be fragmented, or become fragmented as items change.

Answer (score 4):

You would have a single copy of the large list, with two references to it: the variable `x` in the module scope, and `self.mylist` in the scope of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Python class variables are not pointers. But since `largelist.mylist` is pointing to a list, the behaviour of `largelist.mylist` will be like pointers.

This happens in Python with *mutable* types - e.g. - `list`, `dict`.

If `larglist.mylist` is pointing to a string, then the behaviour will be totally different since `str` is an *immutable* type *i.e.* it can't be mutated.

[See this section of Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x) for more info

Comment: This isn't *exactly* correct but it's a good approximation. It would still be a pointer in the case of a string, just pointing to a CPython implemented PyObject-like struct embodying the implementation of Python strings. The fact that this "is immutable" would just be a pure convention of what function pointers that PyObject-like implementation happens to have, and whether or not they happen to raise exceptions when certain operations are attempted, instead of actually carrying out the operations. So under the hood it's still a pointer to something, just not a pointer to a raw C-level value

Comment: This would also be the case with user defined types, since they are also mutable, right?

Comment: @Alexander Whatley Yeah.